# JAVA : Display data in image slider in android from firestore

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display an Image slider to fetch images from urls, for that purpose I am using [this Library](https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider)., and the example code given on the github page of this Library. I have added image urls by creating an Array of ImageUrls and Description, but now I want to fetch those image urls from Firestore.

How can I modify below code, Please help :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);


        //GET DATA FROM FIRESTORE

        db.collection("sliders")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());                                
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });


        List<SliderItem> mSliderItems = new ArrayList<> ();
        mSliderItems.add(new SliderItem ("test1","https://images.pexels.com/photos/218983/pexels-photo-218983.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"));
        mSliderItems.add(new SliderItem ("test2","https://images.pexels.com/photos/747964/pexels-photo-747964.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260"));
        mSliderItems.add(new SliderItem ("test3","https://images.pexels.com/photos/929778/pexels-photo-929778.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"));
        mSliderItems.add(new SliderItem ("test4","https://images.pexels.com/photos/4676400/pexels-photo-4676400.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"));


        SliderView sliderView = findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
        SliderAdapterExample adapter = new SliderAdapterExample(this,mSliderItems);
        sliderView.setSliderAdapter(adapter);
        sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM); //set indicator animation by using IndicatorAnimationType. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
        sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
        sliderView.setAutoCycleDirection(SliderView.AUTO_CYCLE_DIRECTION_BACK_AND_FORTH);
        sliderView.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
        sliderView.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
        sliderView.setScrollTimeInSec(4); //set scroll delay in seconds :
        sliderView.startAutoCycle();
    }

}
```

EDIT :

I tried following edit, but showing context error.

```
SliderAdapterExample adapter = new SliderAdapterExample(this,mSliderItemList);
```

on above line

```
db.collection("sliders")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> () {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                List<SliderItem> mSliderItemList = new ArrayList<> ();
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        SliderItem slideritem = document.toObject(SliderItem.class);
                        mSliderItemList.add(slideritem);
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                    SliderView sliderView = findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
                    SliderAdapterExample adapter = new SliderAdapterExample(this,mSliderItemList);
                    sliderView.setSliderAdapter(adapter);
                    sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM); //set indicator animation by using IndicatorAnimationType. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
                    sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
                    sliderView.setAutoCycleDirection(SliderView.AUTO_CYCLE_DIRECTION_BACK_AND_FORTH);
                    sliderView.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
                    sliderView.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
                    sliderView.setScrollTimeInSec(4); //set scroll delay in seconds :
                    sliderView.startAutoCycle();

                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I guess you're edited code will work fine. If possible post you're logcat error so that I can assist

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved all the images in your **Firebase Storage** then you can directly query from the folder. By this approach you are exempted to add the links into your cloud firestore and thus reducing your read counts.

For querying from a folder from storage.

1. Create a folder in your storage and upload the images.
2. Now add the storage dependency in your project
3. Create a adapter and a model class for the slider library

Now add the below code where you want the slider.

```
FirebaseStorage ST_storage;
SliderView sliderView;

//Code for listing images from storage    
sliderView.setAutoCycle(true);
        sliderView.setScrollTimeInSec(3);
        sliderView.startAutoCycle();
        ST_storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("YOUR_FOLDER_NAME");
        ST_storage.listAll()
                .addOnSuccessListener(listResult -> {
                    for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                        item.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                            safetyTips_items.add(new SafetyTips_Item(Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).toString()));
                            safety_tips_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        });
                    }
                });
        safety_tips_adapter = new SafetyTips_adapter(safetyTips_items);
        sliderView.setSliderAdapter(safety_tips_adapter);
```

With this you can list all the images directly without adding URL's

Comment: But if you really wants to use firestore then let me know I'll post another answer for that.

Comment: yes please. I want to actually use firestore to save image urls .

Comment: I guess adding urls and query them is a useless task and it is very simple to query the images from storage easily. The more images you add in the folder they are automatically queried. Think of it again else please let me know.

Comment: Thank you. But for now Please suggest edit for the getting imageurls from firestore